# AltBeacon: easy way to select a beacon Eddystone

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

This is the only way to select a beacon Eddystone for type?

```
     if (b.getServiceUuid() == 0xfeaa) {
        if (b.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x00) {
            // Eddystone-UID
        } else if (b.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x10) {
            // Eddystone-URL
        } else if (b.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x20) {
            // Eddystone-TLM
        }
    } else {
        // AltBeacon...
    }
```

Comment: the serviceUUID would give you all the beacons user major instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes!**  With [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) version 2.8+, this is much easier.   An optional string identifier has been added to each `BeaconParser`.  This identifier is passed on to any `Beacon` instance that is matched using that parser, so you can easily tell which beacon type is is.

Here's an example of how that works:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser("Eddystone-UID")
  .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

...

if (beacon.getParserIdentifier().equals("Eddystone-UID")) {
  // This is Eddystone-UID
}
```

Just be sure to set the identifier when constructing your `BeaconParser`.

This was added precisely because of the awkwardness of determining the beacon type that is pointed out in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the altbeacon library: http://altbeacon.org

To distinguish beacons use the if statement in this way:

```
if (String.valueOf(beac.getId2()).trim().equals("13191"))//Getting the major of the beacon
                            {
                                //do something
                            }
```

Code wich runs in the UI thread once the beacons are in range:

```
  public void Run(View view){
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        for (Beacon beac : collection) { //LOOP searches for all the beacons within the range...
                            //beac.getId1()// 
                            beaconUUID = beac.getId2().toString(); //Major
                            //beac.getId3()//Minor
                            udaljenost1 = Math.round(beac.getDistance() * 100.0) / 100.0; //dobivanje integera iz decimala, zaokruzivanje na cjeli broj

                            if (String.valueOf(beac.getId2()).trim().equals("13191"))//Getting the major of the beacon
                            {
                                //do something
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });

    }
```